# Outlook calendar only synchronises after logging off and on

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, office365, calendar

Our users have Office 365 and have a shared agenda. When user X adds an appointment in the agenda, the other users don't see the appointment. It's only when user X logs off and logs back in to Windows that the calendar is synchronised.

This happens only for her account, not for the others.

Does anybody have any idea why the calendar isn't synchronised immediately for this particular user, yet it is synchronised immediately for the other users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the sync issue with shared calendar is related with data files. You can [recreate the OST files.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253)

Do you have cached Exchange mode enabled? To avoid syncing issue, we can also try accessing shared calendar online. To do this, go to File > Account Settings > Account Settings. Double click your Exchange account and choose More Settings. Under Advanced tab, unselect “Download shared folders”. Restart Outlook to check the results.

[image]